# What is the result of this javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function getAttackString() { 
    var foo = "d322yvb34"; 
    var bar = "x3nj4nhj9";
return "The code is: "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2);
    }
```

I don't know what "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2)" means.

Comment: [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Comment: Look them all up here. they are properties and methods of `String`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: that's not one giant function. it's just poorly spaced. `+
 foo.substr(3, foo.length-6) + (bar.substr(2)`

Answer (score 1):

This takes a substring of `3` characters (`foo.length-6`) from `foo` starting at string index `3`:

```
foo.substr(3,foo.length-6)
```

This takes the substring of all the characters in `bar` starting from string index `2`:

```
bar.substr(2)
```

It then concatenates them.

The code you posted had a small typo. Here's the working code.

```js
function getAttackString() {
  var foo = "d322yvb34";
  var bar = "x3nj4nhj9";
  return "The code is: " + (foo.substr(3, foo.length - 6)) + bar.substr(2);
}

console.log(getAttackString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look to the parameters of [String#substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> ```
> str.substr(start[, length])
> ```

With this in mind, you could take all parts and do a manual work through of the single parts:

```
indices  012345678               action
string   d322yvb34   
                                 foo.substr(3, foo.length - 6)
            2yv                  foo.substr(3, 9 - 6) 

indices             012345678
string              x3nj4nhj9
                      nj4nhj9    bar.substr(2)

result      2yv       nj4nhj9
```

And get the result

```
2yvnj4nhj9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your full code explained.

```
// getAttackString is a function and the function name is "getAttackString"
     function getAttackString() {
          var foo = "d322yvb34";
          var bar = "x3nj4nhj9";

          //The substr() method extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character 
          //at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.

          return "The code is: " + (foo.substr(3, foo.length - 6)) + bar.substr(2);

          //Lets see what is going on here...
          //       012345678
          //foo = "d322yvb34"
          //(foo.substr(3, foo.length - 6)) + bar.substr(2);
          //Start from 3rd char (this means start at "2yvb34"), 
          //End at (foo.length - 6) i.e 9-6 = 3 = "2yv" 
          //Add bar.substr(2) bar = x3nj4nhj9
          //Start from 2 i.e = "nj4nhj9"
          //Now add "2yv" + "nj4nhj9" = "2yvnj4nhj9"

        }
        console.log(getAttackString())
```